# Associate data to users

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a database in which there is some data like:

```
Data
id|number|page|
1 |------|----|
2 |------|----|
3 |------|----|
```

Let's try to explain what i want to do: I want that, for example, user "A" can access only Data 1 and 2, and NOT 3.

So, technically, I want to store some information in the user table that tells me which Data he can actually download.

Comment: I expect I would add an "auth" field in the data table and in the user table. Then limit access to the data table by the appropriate authorization level.

Comment: Or use a third table to make the `association` between `users Ids` and their related `data`.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a MANY to MANY relation in another table would be ideal.

```
association
user_id, data_id
```

---

```
data
id, number, page
```

---

```
user
id
```